# Cayley Table to Check Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let, $(G,*)$ is a group. We know, no entry appears twice in the Cayley table of this group.

Now let, a Cayley Table is given with no entry appearing twice in a row or column. Let, the existence of identity and inverses are guaranteed in Cayley Table. Then without checking associativity can we say that this Cayley table does represent a group?

For example, consider the Cayley Table for $C=\{1, -1, i, -i\} $ under binary operator $.$

[image: caylay table for complex group]

Here we can easily identify $1$ as a identity. Also we notice that, $1.1=(-1).(-1)=i.(-i)=(-i).i=1$ which guarantees existence of inverse. Now do we need to check associativity to declare $(C, .)$ a group?

Comment: The group table is always a latin square. You're asking the converse.

Comment: I have added some extra things, like existence of identity and inverses are detected.

Answer (score 1):

Associativity is not implied by the Cayley table. For example take $X$ to be a finite set, $\mathcal P(X)$ be its power set. The set difference operation (which is a binary operation) on $\mathcal P(X)$ is not associative : $(A\setminus B)\setminus C\ne A\setminus(B\setminus C)$. If you draw its Cayley table you can see no two elements in a row are the same.

Existence of identity, commutativity, existence of inverses are all implied by the Cayley table.